# Migrate gitlab self hosted to gitlab hosted

Tags: gitlab

I've been using gitlab on a private server for development. Unfortunately, requiring a dual core, 2GB RAM VPS purely for the purpose of holding git repos for a couple of people is not cost effective. I would like to migrate to the free gitlab hosted accounts.

Is there are way to transfer a repo and issues to gitlab hosted servers?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your Gitlab version. They added an [import/export feature](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/settings/import_export.md) in 8.9. If you have a lower version you can update to the current version and export your data afterwards.

> The following items will be exported:
>
> - Project and wiki repositories
> - Project uploads
> - Project configuration including web hooks and services
> - Issues with comments, merge requests with diffs and comments, labels, milestones, snippets, and other project entities
>
> The following items will NOT be exported:
>
> - Build traces and artifacts
> - LFS objects

Comment: Thanks. This has enabled me to export the repo. Unfortunately gitlab.com doesn't appear to have "Gitlab export" import enabled.

Comment: Just found this note in the commercial docs: "You can copy your repos by changing the remote and pushing to the new server; but issues and merge requests can't be imported.".